# Using dropdownlist selection I want to update my web grid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Using dropdown list selection(Application Name) I am updating my web grid here the problem is while returning from controller like this

```
return PartialView("_CreateRoles", objPermList);
```

My dropdown list also getting updated automatically but I don't want this how can I achieve this can you give me any sample example

**Controller**

```
[MustBeLoggedIn,Filters.Compress]  
public ActionResult GetPermissionByAppName(string Appname)
{
    //some coding
    return PartialView("_CreateRoles", objPermList);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<select id="AppList" onchange="AJAXCall_Fun_LinkRole(GetSelected())">
@foreach (var AppName in Model.ApplicationList){
    <option id="hid_AppId">@AppName.AppName</option>
}
</select>
<div id="gridcal" style="padding: 20px;">
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.Permission, rowsPerPage: 20, 
        selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId:"gridcal");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
    @grid.GetHtml(columns:grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("PermName","Permision Name",style:"colWidth")))
```

Comment: Can you please post code samples that show what you are trying to do? And give us a bit more information on what you have tried?

Comment: code please then only we can suggest you something

Comment: sorry I am not able to paste my coding here I am facing dificulty to paste here it's asking to remove unwanted spaces can you see this following lin

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/700629/how-to-update-only-grid-alone-div-tag

Comment: Now I posted code above please see my code

Comment: the code won't compile